# How to connect two GetSplunk Processors in apache nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm creating a simple data flow using GetSplunk Processor.

My goal is to create two different GetSplunk processor for the following reasons.

1. The first `getSplunk` processor will delete the existing data in my own created index.
2. after deleting the data the second `getSplunk` Processor will pull data from a default index in my Splunk local.

I tried dragging two GetSplunk Processors but I can't connect the,

The goal is first to delete the existing data in my index using the first `getSplunk` processor and pull data from _audit index.

Answer (score 0):

GetSplunk does not support incoming relationships because it maintains state and is meant to do incremental extraction (i.e. find new data since last execution). There would need to be a new processor that allowed incoming flow files and did not maintain state. That idea was discussed on this JIRA, but no one has implemented it yet: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-5149